# Swing JFileChooser Accept only ZIP and Directory

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser

How can I make it so a constructed JFileChooser has `setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES)` enabled while filtering out anything that is not a directory or a zip file? The FileChooser should only be able to select and see zip files and directories.

Comment: Use a FileNameExtensionFilter.

Comment: ok, what would the file name extension be for a directory though?

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of `FileNameExtensionFilter` that accepts ZIP files and set it as `FileFilter` of the `JFileChooser`:

```java
var zipFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("ZIP files", "zip");
var chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileFilter(zipFilter);
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
```

<sup>use the corresponding class name instead of `var`, for older versions of Java</sup>

The `FileNameExtensionFilter` will only show files with the given extension or any directory - from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html#accept(java.io.File)):

> The returned FileNameExtensionFilter will accept all directories and any file with a file name extension contained in extensions.